# Time weighted Vega for a VIX future contract

Tags: vix, vega

How to calculate the time weighted Vega applicable for a 3 month future contract (Expiring in 82 days)? Vega with S&P500 as base

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "time weighted" in reference to vega. Where does this term occur? In general 1 VIX future = \$1000 vega, If VIX future goes up 1 point you make \$1000.

Comment: In order to adjust vega exposure based on expiry the time weighting is done (Nothing but multiplying the same with sqrt(30/expiry) for options)